Magnetic field generated from constant coplanar concentric circular electric current
Let electric current run in coplanar concentric circles with radii extending from $0$ to infinity. The current all run in the same circular tangential direction. The current line density across the radius is constant in both location and time. Does the magnetic field generated from the current point in the radial direction and have the same magnitude except when the detection point is along the disk axis?
I can certainly integrate the magnetic field generated from each infinitesimal current to obtain the magnetic field. But is there a more straightforward solution from symmetry especially showing if there is an axial component?
